# Is there a limit for the length of tag names in org mode? (hanging up by long names)

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

In the latest version of org-mode (9.3.6) I get a strange behavior.

Setup:

- empty `init.el` file (just the information to load the latest org-mode package from the elpa directory)
- empty org file
- searching with `agenda-view` for a tag *only* in this file.

If the tag has a long name (for example 26 characters) emacs hangs up -- or I have to wait about 10 seconds to get the expected result: no matches.
If the length is 30 it takes too long, but I can break it with `C-g`.
If the tag has 'normal' length (<20)  everything is fine.

So:

- Is there a recommended limit for the length of tag names? (I couldn't find such a thing in the org manual.) Can I change this limit?
- *Or* do we have a serious bug here?

---

### EDIT:

According to the [advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58063/is-there-a-limit-for-the-length-of-tag-names-in-org-mode-hanging-up-by-long-na#comment90426_58063) of [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) , this is what I get after about 10 seconds. I've used a 'long' tag, 27 character.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  string-match("^&?\\([-+:]\\)?\\({[^}]+}\\|LEVEL\\([<=>]\\{1,2\\}\\)\\([0-9]+\\)\\|\\(\\(?:[[:alnum:]_]+\\(?:\\\\-\\)*\\)+\\)\\([<>=]\\{1,2\\}\\)\\({[^}]+}\\|\"[^\"]*\"\\|-?[.0-9]+\\(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+\\)?\\)\\|[[:alnum:]_@#%]+\\)" "myLeeeengggggthIIIIssssss27")
  org-make-tags-matcher(nil)
  org-tags-view(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-tags-view nil)
  call-interactively(org-tags-view)
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  call-interactively(org-agenda record nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "org-agenda" "org-agenda")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "org-agenda" "org-agenda")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

And that's the 'profiler-report' with the same tag after finishing (about 20 seconds). So the function `org-make-tags-matcher` is guilty?

```
- command-execute                                               34824  99%
 - call-interactively                                           34821  99%
  - funcall-interactively                                       34525  98%
   - execute-extended-command                                   34214  97%
    - command-execute                                           33972  97%
     - call-interactively                                       33957  97%
      - funcall-interactively                                   33957  97%
       - org-agenda                                             33951  97%
        - call-interactively                                    33822  96%
         - funcall-interactively                                33822  96%
          - org-tags-view                                       33822  96%
           - org-make-tags-matcher                              33812  96%
            - completing-read                                     424   1%
             - completing-read-default                            424   1%
              - read-from-minibuffer                              107   0%
               + redisplay_internal (C function)                   22   0%
               - timer-event-handler                                2   0%
                  apply                                             2   0%
           - org-agenda-prepare                                     4   0%
            - org-agenda-mode                                       4   0%
               require                                              4   0%
             org-compile-prefix-format                              4   0%
           - org-agenda-fit-window-to-buffer                        2   0%
            - org-fit-window-to-buffer                              2   0%
               fit-window-to-buffer                                 2   0%
        - org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command                  129   0%
         + read-char-exclusive                                     84   0%
         - org-switch-to-buffer-other-window                       17   0%
          - apply                                                  17   0%
           + switch-to-buffer-other-window                         17   0%
           pos-visible-in-window-p                                  4   0%
         - org-fit-window-to-buffer                                 3   0%
            fit-window-to-buffer                                    3   0%
       + profiler-report                                            6   0%
       autoload-do-load                                            15   0%
    + execute-extended-command--shorter                           166   0%
    + sit-for                                                      76   0%
   + find-file                                                    308   0%
  + byte-code                                                     296   0%
 - autoload-do-load                                                 3   0%
  - byte-code                                                       3   0%
   - substitute-key-definition                                      3   0%
    - map-keymap                                                    3   0%
     + #<compiled 0x11895c1>                                        3   0%
- ...                                                              86   0%
   Automatic GC                                                    72   0%
 + minibuffer-complete                                             14   0%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                   3   0%
```

Here another report but with the short tag 'tag'. A huge difference:

```
- command-execute                                                 720  94%
 - call-interactively                                             720  94%
  - funcall-interactively                                         583  76%
   - execute-extended-command                                     555  72%
    - execute-extended-command--shorter                           350  45%
     - completion-try-completion                                  350  45%
      - completion--nth-completion                                350  45%
       - completion--some                                         350  45%
        - #<compiled 0x12e981d>                                   350  45%
         + completion-pcm-try-completion                          245  32%
           completion-basic-try-completion                        105  13%
    - command-execute                                             143  18%
     - call-interactively                                         126  16%
      - funcall-interactively                                     126  16%
       - org-agenda                                               116  15%
        - call-interactively                                       79  10%
         - funcall-interactively                                   79  10%
          - org-tags-view                                          79  10%
           - org-make-tags-matcher                                 70   9%
            + completing-read                                      66   8%
            - org-global-tags-completion-table                      4   0%
             - org-agenda-files                                     4   0%
              + mapcar                                              4   0%
           - org-agenda-prepare                                     6   0%
            - org-agenda-prepare-window                             3   0%
             - org-switch-to-buffer-other-window                    3   0%
              + apply                                               3   0%
            - org-agenda-mode                                       3   0%
               require                                              3   0%
           - org-agenda-fit-window-to-buffer                        3   0%
            - org-fit-window-to-buffer                              3   0%
               fit-window-to-buffer                                 3   0%
        - org-agenda-get-restriction-and-command                   37   4%
           read-char-exclusive                                     25   3%
         - org-switch-to-buffer-other-window                        3   0%
          + apply                                                   3   0%
       + profiler-report                                           10   1%
     + autoload-do-load                                            17   2%
    + sit-for                                                      62   8%
   + minibuffer-complete-and-exit                                  28   3%
  + byte-code                                                     137  17%
+ ...                                                              43   5%
```

Comment: Toggle on `debug-on-quit`: when you interrupt it with `C-g` you should get a backtrace. That should be helpful in determinining what's going on. Also, if you can run  a [profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling) that would also help. You probably should limit the profile to `org-*` at first, to reduce the amount of data.

Comment: It may well be that `org-make-tags-matcher` becomes exponentially slow for very long tags. You should probably report this to the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html) as a bug - use `org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: And if I may be forgiven an editorial comment, that regex in `org-make-tags-matcher` looks disgusting.

Comment: FWIW I see this too.